# Select rows by max value of another row

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, max

I'm doing this using the sql in Access...

This has been probably answered before but I don't know how to ask the right question so I can't find the solution.

I have table named "Table":

```
 attr_1  attr_2  attr3
 1       A       10
 1       B       5
 2       C       3
 3       D       7
 3       E       8
 3       F       11
```

I want the result grouped by `attr_1` where `attr3` has max value and also the `attr_2` from that same row. So this is what I need as a result:

```
 1      A       10
 2      C       3
 3      F       11
```

If I don't need the `attr_2` then I would know how to do this with GROUP BY and MAX but I don't know how to include this `attr_2` in the sql statement to get the wanted result.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `group by` at all.  You just want to choose the most recent row.  Assuming the value is unique, you can do:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where t.attr3 = (select max(t2.attr3) from table as t2 where t2.attr_1 = t.attr_1);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get maximum value in `subquery` AND `join` to the table to get all values.

```
SELECT attr_1, attr_2, attr3
FROM (
  SELECT attr_1, max(attr3) as maxAttr3
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY attr_1 )T
JOIN Table1 T1
on T.maxAttr3 = T1.attr3
and T.attr_1 = T1.attr_1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. This looks good but I'm getting the syntax error... I'm trying to find the cause now

Comment: It says: syntax error in FROM clause (I just created the same table as I described in my question - that one was for example - just to make sure, but still the same error). I even add the same inconsistency in attribut names :)

Comment: @Bezk -- Nothing looks wrong with this syntax.  Make sure you use the correct table name (this example uses `Table1`)...

Comment: I'm getting there. The second (inner) Select works. It seems access has something against naming the table "Table" :). Will report my progress...

Comment: I got it to work. I had to change the first row to  "SELECT Table1.attr_1, attr_2, attr3", and had to add "inner join" instead "join". This is maybe some Access things that don't apply to other databases...? Also it gives me the same result with or without the last row "and T.attr_1 = T1.attr_1"?? Thank you again for your effort but Gordon's solution worked right out of box so I had to mark his answer...